# jQuery UI Dialog is transparent

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have this jQuery UI Dialog:

```
<div id="dialog">
    <p>Add your thoughts</p>
    <textarea name = "textarea1" id = "textarea1" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button1" onclick="myfunction()" value="Send!" />
</div>
```

It looks transparent when I call this dialog, how can I make it have a distinct colour? I went through the documentation but I couldn't find a way to change it. Thanks.

Comment: `myfunction()`?? how do we reproduce this?

Comment: Why visibility hidden???

Comment: Visibility becomes visible after an action. And my function is not related with the color of the dialog.

Comment: Don't place styles directly on HTML markup, it's horrible IMO. Provide an external stylesheet for your project and reference the elements for styling there. [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t4msft28/1/)

Comment: @jason you wants to change background color??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set to all class background with use !important.

```
{background:yellow !important}​
```

with the class name preceding the brackets

See here :http://jsfiddle.net/dEvKb/15/

Comment: There is no reason hack around this. 9 times out of 10, this happens because you forgot the CSS reference at the top of the file `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./jqueryui_1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">` Look at Chamika's answer for more details

Answer (score 8):

You have to add the jQuery UI css reference

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/osb8sesm/)